# com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am going through strange error, i am running spring boot locally and connecting to AWS Dynamodb, it returns below exception:

> EVENT>{"@timestamp":"2018-04-03T17:57:33.173+10:00","@Version":1,"message":"Error while creating connection with DynamoDB","logger_name":"com.DynamoDBRepository","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"name":"xyz","apiVersion":"1","application":"xyz","version":"1.6.37","type":"ERROR"}
>   com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443 [dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/52.94.13.132] failed: connect timed out
>   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1069)

Connection code:

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfiguration.withProxyHost("http.com");
        clientConfiguration.withProxyPort(8080);
        clientConfiguration.withProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);
        clientConfiguration.withProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
        AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
                .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_2).build();
```

However, this error do not appear when i run my code through public internet.

Comment: Can you post your DynamoDB connection code for when you try and connect locally and remotely?

Comment: I am getting different error:

com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: null (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 407; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)

Comment: Thanks i am able to fix it, rather giving "localhost" to withProxyHost i was giving "http:localhost". This was causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

#### With proxy

If you want to setup a connection to DynamoDB through a proxy, be careful how you configure your pricy settings:

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();

clientConfiguration.setProxyHost("yourProxyHost");
clientConfiguration.setProxyPort(8080);
clientConfiguration.setProxyUsername("proxyUsername");
clientConfiguration.setProxyPassword("proxyPassword");

   
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
                .withRegion(Regions.YOUR_REGION)
                .build();
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html

#### Without proxy

If you are facing similar issue but not utilizing a proxy connection, then I suggest testing your host has a valid network path the the internet, or if in a private subnet on AWS it has a DynamoDB VPC Endpoint attached.